# How to test deletion in JUnit (Play Framework)?

Tags: java, frameworks, junit, playframework-2.1

I need to make a JUnit test that checks whether it is possible to delete something from the database. I'm using the Play 2.1 Framework with an in-memory database.

I tried assertNull(...), but that failed. I then tried assertNotNUll(...) and the test passes, but I'm not sure this is the best way to do it or that it can even confirm deletion. **Is there a better way to check if an item has been deleted?** Should I look up the object and expect an error?

Here's my code (I also have some @BeforeClass and @AfterClass code, but it's no relevant to my question):

```
@Test
public void UserDelete(){
    // Test ID: 3
    // creating a new user
    User user = new User();
    user.id = (long) 4;
    user.facebookId = "0000004";
    user.email = "test4@gmail.com";
    user.name = "name4";
    user.save();

    // deleting the user
    user.delete();

    // checking deletion
    assertNotNull(user);
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a hint regarding what the user.delete() method contains? If I understood correctly when you call user.delete() you perform a delete in your database. That means the user remains unaffected. What you should do is try to query the database for the deleted user and see that it was removed. Unless you change the instance "user" in the delete() method it will never be null.

Answer (score 0):

In general you usually have to do something like this. Of course this is a crude example but it points out that you should use some persistence solution like JPA to persist your domain objects.

```
@Test(expected = WhateverObjectNotFoundException.class) 
public void removeUserTest(){
    User u = UserFactory.createTestUser();
    Long id = myEntityManager.persist(u);
    assertNotNull(id);
    myEntityManager.remove(u);
    myEntityManager.findById(id);
}
```

In my opinion the `User` shouldn't be responsible for its lifecycle since it does not make sense to ask an object to delete itself hence your question is somewhat paradox.

This solution later can be generalized so you won't have to write it all over again when you test for the same kind of behavior.

Comment: Play documentation, actually, recommends using Active Record style DB access.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert new object in DB, check that is was inserted, delete it and check that it was deleted. Most obvious way is to use `select count(*)` to get number of rows.

```
public class ApplicationTest extends WithApplication {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        start(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase("default-test"), fakeGlobal()));
    }

    @Test
    public void UserModify() {
        // create user (User extends Model)
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1);
        user.setName("name1");
        user.save();

        int rowCount = Ebean.find(User.class).where().eq("id", 1).findRowCount();
        assertEquals(1, rowCount);

        user.delete();

        rowCount = Ebean.find(User.class).where().eq("id", 1).findRowCount();
        assertEquals(0, rowCount);
    }
}
```